# PythonAnywhere scheduler return codes

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

When I look at my logs from scheduled tasks at PythonAnywhere I see they are full of statements such as:

- 2012-06-07 11:09:16 -- Completed task, took 11.00 seconds, return code was 0.
- 2012-06-08 14:41:41 -- Completed task, took 19957.00 seconds, return code was 137.
- 2012-06-08 17:33:32 -- Completed task, took 5068.00 seconds, return code was 143.
- 2012-06-07 09:09:06 -- Completed task, took 1.00 seconds, return code was 1.
- 2012-06-08 17:29:04 -- Completed task, took 0.00 seconds, return code was 126.

What isn't clear to me is what is issuing these return codes. Is it bash? Is it Python? And is there a list of them available?

Comment: It would have been nice to be able to tag this with pythonanywhere, but the tag doesn't exist. Anyone with 1500 rep care to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PA dev here. We report the return code from the process that is being run and the meaning of the return code is dependent on the process that is being called. Bash has some reserved exit codes listed here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html.

In PA, the logs for your scheduled tasks will usually contain more information than the return code can give you.